# How to extract substring from POSIX message?

Tags: c, posix, message-queue

I have a server-client program, the client sends the server a message using a `struct` that has three major values: a date, and two timestamps.

Now, when the server receives the message, I try to extract the date from the message struct as a substring of the character array and then convert it to an int, but I've been stuck for hours now even trying to get the relevant characters from the message.

My server program:

```
#include "msg.h"

const char *months[] = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};

void delete_mq(char* mname, mqd_t qid) {
    if (mq_close(qid) < 0) {
        perror("Error closing queue");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (mq_unlink(mname) < 0) {
        perror("Error unlinking queue");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void make_command(MESSAGE *mess, char *mname, mqd_t qid) {
    printf("making command, hehe\n");
    if (strcmp(mess->date,"STOP") == 0){
            printf("Stopping the server.\n");
            delete_mq(mname, qid);
            exit(0);
    }

    // this is where I am stuck
    char thedate[3];
    char *date = mess->date;
    strncpy(thedate, date+1, 1);
    thedate[2] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", thedate);
    
    strcpy(mess->messtext,"Some text respone message");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int flagsc = O_RDONLY | O_CREAT;
    mode_t mode = 0600;

    struct mq_attr attr;
    attr.mq_flags = 0;
    attr.mq_maxmsg = 10;
    attr.mq_msgsize = sizeof(MESSAGE);
    attr.mq_curmsgs = 0;
    
    int flags = O_WRONLY;
    char cname[10];
    char sqname[15];
    sprintf(sqname,"%s%s",qname,getlogin());

    mqd_t qid = mq_open(sqname, flagsc, mode, &attr);

    if (qid <0) {
        perror("Error opening message queue");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (;;) {
        MESSAGE message;
        unsigned int priority = 0;

        if (mq_receive(qid, (char*) &message, sizeof(message), &priority) != -1) {
            make_command(&message, qname, qid);
            sprintf(cname,"/%d", message.pid);
            message.pid = getpid();
            mqd_t cmqid = mq_open(cname, flags);
            mq_send(cmqid, (char*)&message, sizeof(MESSAGE), 0);
            mq_close(cmqid);
        }
    }

    mq_close(qid);
    return 0;
}
```

My client program:

```
// ./client 11.23. 13:24 16:43
#include "msg.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc != 4){
        printf("Usage: ./client <date e.g. 11.23.> <time1 e.g. 13:24> <time2 e.g. 16:43>\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int flags = O_WRONLY;
    int cflags = O_RDONLY|O_CREAT;
    mode_t mode = 0600;
    char sqname[15];
    sprintf(sqname,"%s%s", qname, getlogin());
    mqd_t qid = mq_open(sqname, flags);

    if (qid == -1) {
        perror("Error opening queue in client");
        exit(1);
    }

    struct mq_attr temp;

    if (mq_getattr(qid, &temp) == -1) {
        perror("Error with getattr in client");
    } else {
         // finish later
    }

    char cqname[20];

    struct mq_attr attr;
    attr.mq_flags = 0;
    attr.mq_maxmsg = 8;
    attr.mq_msgsize = sizeof(MESSAGE);
    attr.mq_curmsgs = 0;

    sprintf(cqname,"/%d", getpid());
    mqd_t cqid = mq_open(cqname, cflags, mode, &attr);

    if (cqid == -1) {
        perror("Error opening queue in client");
        exit(1);
    }

    MESSAGE mess;
    strcat(mess.date, argv[1]);
    strcat(mess.time1, argv[2]);
    strcat(mess.time2, argv[3]);

    mess.pid = getpid();

    printf("Client has sent request");

    if (mq_send(qid, (char*) &mess, sizeof(MESSAGE), 0) < 0) {
        perror("Error sending message in client");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (strcmp(mess.date,"STOP") != 0) {
        if (mq_receive(cqid,(char*) &mess, sizeof(MESSAGE), 0) < 0) {
            perror("Error receiving message in client");
            exit(1);
        }
    } else {
        printf("Stopping the client.\n");

        if(mq_close(qid) < 0) {
            perror("error closing server queue");
            exit(1);
        }

        if(mq_close(cqid) < 0) {
            perror("error closing client queue");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (mq_unlink(cqname) < 0) {
            perror("Error unlinking client queue");
            exit(1);
        }
        exit(0);
    }

    printf("%s\n", mess.messtext);

    if(mq_close(qid) < 0) {
            perror("error closing server queue");
            exit(1);
    }

    if(mq_close(cqid) < 0) {
        perror("error closing client queue");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (mq_unlink(cqname) < 0) {
        perror("Error unlinking client queue");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    exit(0);
}
```

And the header:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <mqueue.h>

#define KEY 1111

typedef struct{ 
    int pid;
    // e.g. 11.23.
    char date[50];
    char time1[50];
    char time2[50];
    char messtext[10];  
} MESSAGE;

char * qname="/server_";
```

Now, the arguments for a client execution should be a date, and two timestamps. When the server receives the message, I want to extract the first two characters from `date` (the month) and convert it to `int` so that I could get the relevant month from `*months[]`.

I tried pretty much everything: `strcpy`, `memcpy`, `sprintf` and I'm going nuts, because it will either only print the first number of the month, or won't convert correctly, or print extra crazy characters from memory, and I've barely started to break the message down into parts. The `mess->date` apparently has some other character on its first position, and I can't manage to skip it.

Could someone help me achieve what I described?

Comment: `atoi` https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/

Comment: I have tried `atoi`, I know what it's for but I can't even get to the point where I would have to use it. I can't extract the month from the character array.

Comment: `strncpy(thedate, date+1, 1)` means _copy 1 char from the string starting at `date+1` to `thedate`_.  So if `date` is the string "Jan 20", you'd read the `a` in "Jan" only because `date+1` is the string "an 20", and you only copy 1 char. I suspect you might want `strncpy(thedate, date, 3)` if you're reading month names like "Jan", "Feb", etc. Also keep in mind that `thedate` will not be null-terminated due to your declaration `char thedate[3];` which restricts you to functions like `strncpy/memcpy` and `strncmp/memcmp` that require a parameter specifying the max number of chars to examine.

Comment: No, `date` is the string "11.23.", but when I print it, it has some extra character on the first position, so I tried `strncpy(thedate, date+1, 2)`, but this doesn't work either, for some reason it won't copy `11` into `thedate`. Also note that I did terminate `thedate` with `'\0'`.

Comment: `MESSAGE mess;` in your client code declares `mess` with no initializer, so `strcat(mess.date, argv[1]);` could append the string "11.23." to uninitialized/garbage data.  You can fix that bug using `MESSAGE mess = { -1 };` to initialize the `pid` field to an invalid PID.  The rest of the data in the structure would be initialized with zeroes, and `strcat` would work as expected. That may not be the full solution, but it's a start.